# Route not working - very confusing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, controller, routes

I understand the concept with routes, but now and then they just don't work as they should. In this specific case I'm trying to get the route for editing a project to work, but I get the following error message:

```
No route matches [POST] "/projects/8/edit"
```

**routes.rb:**

```
Ampta::Application.routes.draw do
  get "home/index"

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  resources :projects do
    collection do
      get "manage" 
    end 
  end

  resources :projects
  resources :tickets
  resources :projects_users
  resources :users

  root :to => 'home#index'

end
```

**Controller:**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def edit
        // no code yet
    end
end
```

**View:**

```
<% @users_projects.each do |project| %>
    <%= link_to project.title, project_path(project), :class => "manage_project_link" %>
    <%= button_to "Edit", edit_project_path(project), :class => "btn edit_button" %>
<% end %>
```

What is wrong? The route is to be found when running *rake routes*

```
 edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)       projects#edit
```

Comment: why are you adding `projects` routes two times.. second one is not needed(i.e) `resources :projects`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look more closely to the error message:

`No route matches [POST] "/projects/8/edit"`

It's actually using the verb `POST` and not `GET`. That's why it's not finding the route.

You are using the [button_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) helper that generates a form, the default method being `POST`.

You just need to change `button_to` to `link_to`.

Comment: Ok, didn't now that. Thanks a lot!